# MATLAB Figure as Windows Enhanced Metafile Issues

Tags: matlab

I am having an issue with a figure I have been trying to create in MATLAB. Let me provide you with some reference and background before going into the details.

I am in the process of finishing up a report for school and I am trying to ensure my results are displayed clearly and professionally. I cannot use LaTeX (this is FIXED, believe me I would rather use it) and so I am typesetting it in MS Word.

In general, I have found that using MATLAB to create the plots of my data has yielded very nice results. Specifically, I have found the .emf files to give the best images (they are vector images as far as I can tell, they don't pixelate/degrade when zoomed in). I am using MATLAB 2016b.

In MS Word I am doing the following:

1. Insert
2. Text
3. Quick Parts
4. Fields
5. IncludePicture
6. Then I link the file in the dialog box and also check the "resize horizontally and vertically from source" boxes.

In MATLAB I do the following:

1. Create figure using `plot`
2. Use the figure handle (e.g. `MyFig.Property = Something`) to set `PaperUnits` to inches
3. Use the figure handle `PaperPosition = [ 0 0 6 4 ]` (corresponds to a figure 6 inches wide by 4 inches tall
4. Finally, I use the `saveas` function to save the figure as a `meta` file (Windows Enhanced metafile, .emf)

The end result is exactly what I want and appears in the MS Word document as a vector image (as described above, maintains the vector image quality when saving the word doc as a PDF). I can easily update the plots in the word doc by updating all the fields. I appreciate this workflow/automation and would like to maintain it if possible.

My issue comes when I try to apply this process to one of my plots which requires two y-axis. What I do different in this figure from the rest is as follows:

1. Use `yyaxis` `left` and `right` to create the two y-axes
2. Use the `YAxis` property of `gca` to align the tick marks of the two y-axes
3. From there onward I apply the same MATLAB process for saving the figure as described above.

The issue is that the saved .emf file is NOT a vector image (unlike the others). It clearly looks worse and it pixelates when I zoom in. If I remove the second y-axis it works fine again.

Does anyone have any ideas on the y-axis on what might be causing this and how I can resolve it? I've tried the following with no success:

- varying the size from the 6x4 inches
- unchecking the "resize horizontally and vertically boxes in MS Word"
- varying the font size of the figure (making it smaller)

Am I going about saving my figures correctly or is there a better way to do this?

Is there any additional information I can provide to help resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue.

The problem seemed to be that when I added a second axis to the plot MATLAB defaulted to a different renderer for the figure. Specifically, one that creates a bitmap image hence the garbage quality of the final product. I have no idea *why* it did it but the trigger for doing so (as it defaulted to the correct renderer for all plots with a single y-axis) was the second y-axis.

I fixed the issue by simply forcing the specific figure to render using the appropriate renderer (called "painters", see below).

`myfig.Renderer = 'painters';`